# LEFT OUTER JOIN 2 datatables

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to understand how to query, preferably with LINQ, 2 datatables.
I would like to do a LEFT OUTER JOIN on them

Datatable1 with col's: [ID] [colA]
DataTable2 with col's: [ID] [ColB] [ColC] ...

Looking to join on that ID.

Can someone please show me an example so I can apply it to the datatables I have?   Thank you in advance

Comment: have you tried this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx or this even: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388969/join-two-tables-in-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This compiles and does what you would expect based on the result set given:

```
// create the default row to be used when no value found
var defaultRow = DataTable2.NewRow();
defaultRow[0] = 0;
defaultRow[1] = String.Empty;

// the query
var result = from x in DataTable1.AsEnumerable()
    join y in DataTable2.AsEnumerable() on (string)x["ID"] equals (string)y["ID"] 
             into DataGroup
    from row in DataGroup.DefaultIfEmpty<DataRow>(defaultRow)
    select new {a = x["ColA"], b = (string)row["ColB"]};
```

Comment: This looks like it will work and I am trying it out now. My program takes some time to populate the databases initially, but I will report back once complete.
Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

To get a `LEFT OUTER Join`

*and you should try using @Joanna link.*

```
from x in DataTable1
join y in DataTable2 on x.ID equals y.ID into DataGroup
from item in DataGroup.DefaultIfEmpty(new y.ColB = String.Empty , y.ColC = String.Empty})
select new {x.ColA, item.ColB , item.ColC}
```

**UPDATE**

Given what you provide you should look for LINQ-Dataset articles

Here is the code snippet

```
DataTable DataTable1 = new DataTable();
DataTable DataTable2 = new DataTable();

DataTable1.Columns.Add("ID");
DataTable1.Columns.Add("ColA");
DataTable1.Rows.Add(1, "A");
DataTable1.Rows.Add(2, "B");    

DataTable2.Columns.Add("ID");
DataTable2.Columns.Add("ColB");
DataTable2.Rows.Add(1, "B");

var result = from x in DataTable1.AsEnumerable()
             join y in DataTable2.AsEnumerable() on x["ID"] equals y["ID"] into DataGroup                         
             from item in DataGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new {
                            ID = x["ID"],
                            ColA = x["ColA"],
                            ColB = item == null ? string.Empty : item["ColB"]
                        };
foreach (var s in result)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", s);
```

Comment: I guess part of what confuses me on your example and everyone elses example is there is no x.ID for me. Should there be a x.ID? 
or should I be doing something like x.Table.Columns["ID"] instead of x.ID?
What could I be doing wrong that I don't get X.ID?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you done so far ? can you tell us more why are you not getting x.ID ?

Comment: For example here is code from the start to try and match yours as closely as possible.
http://codepaste.net/ic84es
If I dont use .AsEnumerable() then it gives me a error on DataTable1 saying GroupJoin not found.
 IF I add AsEnumerable() which one of the examples i found while searching showed to do for datatables, then the next error is X.ID because there is no .ID. I just get what is normal for a DataRow.

Thank you again for your help.

Comment: refer the the UPDATE post. You should refering LINQ-Dataset since there are too many specific LINQ topic around.

Comment: @Turbot - lol, that was exactly what I did a moment ago to work around passing in a row to DefaultIfEmpty, but then I found a way of doing it after all.

Answer (score -1):

To get an inner join try this

```
from x in Datatable1
join y in Datatable2 on x.ID equals y.ID
select new {x.colA, y.ColB, y.ColC }
```

Comment: I guess part of what confuses me on your example and everyone elses example is there is no x.ID for me. Should there be a x.ID? or should I be doing something like x.Table.Columns["ID"] instead of x.ID? What could I be doing wrong that I don't get X.ID? Thank you for your help.

Comment: the question was: "LEFT OUTER JOIN 2 datatables"