# LEFT JOIN DataTables - how do I get this to work?

Tags: c#, linq, join, datatable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LEFT OUTER JOIN 2 datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403006/left-outer-join-2-datatables)

Let's say this is my exact code:

```
        DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
        DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
        DataTable joinedtable = new DataTable();

        table1.Columns.Add("ID");
        table1.Columns.Add("ColA");
        table1.Rows.Add(1, "A");

        table2.Columns.Add("ID");
        table2.Columns.Add("ColB");
        table2.Rows.Add(1, "B");
```

What would my query, LINQ or not, but to left join table1 and table2 together and put it into joinedTable?
When I try to search for examples, I keep finding examples that start like this:

```
        var result = from x in table1
            join y in table2 on x.ID equals y.ID
```

But, I get an error on DataTable1 which I found a suggestion to instead do      "table1.AsEnumerable()" but then I do not have a x.ID. .ID is not defined. I only have things for x that a normal DataRow would have.
What am I doing wrong here? I cannot seem to figure this out.

Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: @dash I have using System.Data;, which should include .Data.DataSetExtensions, correct? I assume so, but would like to confirm.
Thank you.

Comment: Nope - you need System.Data.DataSetExtensions - this is specifically for, well, Linqyfying your DataTables. Well, not specifically, but it helps. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.aspx (which are in the DataSetExtensions and add the functionality you are after) Are they in the references for your project? If they are, then please ignore my comment.

Comment: @user1308743 - any reason for posting the same question twice ? You can edit the original question to add more information.

Comment: Ah, I see your real problem. The answer is in the other question - you access the columns through the indexer for the DataRow - x.Field<"Id">, or x["Id"] for example. This is fine and constitutes your join condition. The answer is in your other post :-) @Joanna has answered your question, too. No need for double posting!

Comment: @dash visual studio is telling me that DataSetExtensions does not exist in System.Data. I tried adding a referance to it in NET and it was there to add, but it still says it not does not exist for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: Nope - you are fine, please ignore my comment - there is sometimes an issue with the DataSetExtensions not being available, but this is not that time. Your question has been answered over on your other thread, so I'd go and check there. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

With `DataTables` it unfortunately becomes kind of tricky (if you don't want to use a `LINQ` for any reason), cause you need to define [DataRelation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarelation.aspx) object that *actually* define the relationship defintion between those two `DataTables`.

For more information can have a look on this explanation :

[How to join two DataTables using C#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/f122d7f4-3b7d-4d93-bd0f-8bb57cd990a4)

Comment: I am OK with using LINQ, I just can't seem to get it to work. Could you possibly show me a simple example using the simple datatables I set up above? The examples I find I can't seem to get to work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Here's a complete implementation of a dataset join helper class >> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326080/en-us